# How to explain slick.js / slick-theme.css strange dot style loading issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

In my testing of **slick.js front-end slider plugin**, I found in Chrome browser, sometimes the navigation dot in class ".slick-dots li button:before"

[image: Chrome browser, sometimes the navigation dot in class ".slick-dots li button:before" suddenly became **content: 'â€¢';**]

suddenly changed

from

**content: '•';**

to

**content: 'â€¢';**

by itself. 
However, I wanted the dots 
to display

as

[image]

instead of

[image]

It's wierd when i use incognito to refresh page, it turns back to normal again, but if it already became image 2 via unknown trigger, you are just not able to refresh these dots back to normal in any none-incognito mode;

so what could be the cause of the issue and how to avoid it?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: as it's not easy to reproduce as i didn't find what triggered it, in chrome also seldom happens. all I noticed is the above css run-time style got changes. the ones i've highlighted in <bold> font-weight

Comment: Unless someone has already run into this issue and knows the solution you won't get any answers from people debugging an image.

Comment: This happens occasionally, a lot of other scripts and css are also loaded with it together in a more complex deployment ,so  it's not easy to purify the scenario and still see the effect, if I got time will try.

Comment: I am running into the same problem -- did you find a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by your code editor. Make sure u saving file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: A Very reasonable answer, yup I am also thinking what could make the chrome browser suddenly change the real-time css character value from '•' to 'â€¢' . but I checked in my php header file I've used <meta charset="utf-8">.

Comment: You need to be really sure that code editor saving file in utf-8 encoding. Meta tag isn't enough.